# Как конвертировать FileStream в Stream?

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, filestream

Я открыл файл и считал его в поток, теперь мне при вызове метода нужно данный поток передать дальше, но возникает ошибка в том что Stream != FileStream. Как правильно конвертировать FileStream в Stream и передать его на выполнение?

```
using (var fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
{
    var buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
    fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    await _conversationsRepository.Attachment(new Attachment
    {
        Name = Path.GetFileName(file),
        Stream = fileStream
    });
}

public bool Attachment(Attachment attachment)
{
    if (attachment.Stream == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attachment.Name))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (attachment.Stream.Length > 30 * 1024 * 1024)
    {
        return false;
    }
    console.log("true");
    return true;
}
```

Вот сам класс:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Models
{
    public class Attachment
    {
        public Stream Stream { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public AttachmentType Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Если делаю так, то stream остается пуст.

```
var stream = Stream.Null;
fileStream.CopyTo(stream);

var stream2 = new MemoryStream();
fileStream.CopyTo(stream2);
```

Comment: Здрасьте... Как вы собрались копировать в нулевой поток?) Создайте хотя бы MemoryStream. Нулевой поток используется, как заглушка, а для хранения данных непригоден.

Comment: поделитесь, что вы передаете и какая у вас ошибка при передаче?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov если передаю поток, то метод не срабатывает, если не передаю его - то все работает. Ошибок дебагер никаких не выдает..

Comment: `System.IO.FileStream` **is** `System.IO.Stream`. Файлстрим является стримом. Такое присваивание обязано работать. Может быть, `Stream` в классе `Attachment` относится к другому пространству имен? Ну так приведите **точное** описание ошибки.

Comment: @Sanvirtus как вы определили что метод не срабатывает?

Comment: А вы позицию в файловом потоке сбрасывание на ноль? Судя по вашему коду, вы открываете для чтения файл, оттуда зачем-то считывание буффер, который не используете, а потом видимо пробуете копировать в новый поток. CopyTo копирует из текущего потока с текущей! позиции, а так как вы уже считали из файла все данные в буффер, то позиция чтения находится в самом конце и ничего, соответственно, не копируется.

Comment: @John делал по примеру: https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.14.php

Comment: @Sanvirtus ну нужно было бы разобраться, что они делают. Они этот буфер считывают, потому что хранят именно его, а не какой-то поток. А в вашем случае, если вам всё же нужен поток, который будет находится в памяти, то буффер можно не создавать вообще и сразу FileStream копировать в только что созданный MemoryStream.

Comment: @John мне нужен именно поток, так как сделать так что бы он передавался через метод? В том методе я еще не реализовал, но будет сохранение в бд.

Comment: `public Stream Stream { get; set; }` - эта строка вам не о чём не говорит ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена следующим способом:

```
using (var fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
{
    var buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
    fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    await _conversationsRepository.Attachment(new Attachment
    {
        Name = Path.GetFileName(file),
    }, buffer);
}

public bool Attachment(Attachment attachment, byte[] buffer)
{
    Attachment.Stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    if (attachment.Stream == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attachment.Name))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (attachment.Stream.Length > 30 * 1024 * 1024)
    {
        return false;
    }
    console.log("true");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Stream предок класса FileStream, то есть можно просто сделать апкаст.

```
FileStream filestream = ...
Stream b = filestream;
```

UPD: 
Попробуйте так: 
замените

```
using (var fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
   {
    var buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
    fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    await _conversationsRepository.Attachment(new Attachment
    {
        Name = Path.GetFileName(file),
        Stream = fileStream
    });
    }
```

на

```
 await _conversationsRepository.Attachment(new Attachment
 {
    Name = Path.GetFileName(file),
    Stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open)
 });
```

Comment: В коде как раз это показано в самом начале (Stream = fileStream) но возникает ошибка в методе.

Comment: а если без using? он же освобождает за собой память вроде, при дальнейшем использовании будут проблемы. И буфер вам явно не нужен, как писали выше.  Попробуйте сразу передать в Ваш метод fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open)

Comment: @Sanvirtus покажите ошибку

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц ошибки дебагер не выдает, просто останавливается работа приложения и все.

Comment: @Ksandr и так тоже не работает. Убрал на том конце все проверки. Если stream передаю - ничего не выводится в консоль и программа останавливается. Если не передаю, то все работает.

Comment: @Sanvirtus, В варианте "не передаю" вы убираете  await _conversationsRepository... целиком? Возможно, проблема в await? Если задача после await не завершается, то выглядеть это будет так, как Вы описали - просто останавливается выполнение.  Попробуйте заменить await на какое-то ожидание, скажем, Thread.Sleep(5000); после строки с await

Answer (score -1):

Создавайте MemoryStream.

```
using (var fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
{
   MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
   fileStream.CopyTo(stream)

   await _conversationsRepository.Attachment(new Attachment
   {
      Name = Path.GetFileName(file),
      Stream = stream
   });
}
```

Это должно сработать, при условии, что у вас размер файла будет удовлетворять условию: > 30 * 1024 * 1024.

UPD: Я так прикинул, лучше уж напрямую передавать файловый поток в Attachment.

```
var fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open);

await _conversationsRepository.Attachment(new Attachment
{
    Name = Path.GetFileName(file),
    Stream = fileStream;
 });
```

Так как хранить 30Мб в памяти дело затратное.

Comment: Хм, файл весом 4 кб (4024 байт). Метод не срабатывает. Если закомментить передачу Stream и проверки, то все срабатывает..В чем же проблема блин? Ошибок никаких дебагер не выдает. Просто останавливается программа и все.

Comment: Может ошибка в методе? Может нужно не больше 30*1024*1024, а меньше этого числа проверять?

Comment: убрал проверки вообще все. Если передаю stream - ничего. Не передаю - все выводится

Comment: @Sanvirtus а что выводится? Что вообще должно происходить после проверки на условие?

Comment: убрал все проверки. Сделал просто вывод messagebox. если метод срабатывает - выскакивает messagebox, не срабатывает - не выскакивает. при передаче stream он не выскакивает. без stream - выскакивает

Comment: @Sanvirtus как именно выглядит теперь метод Attachment? Если вы и правда совсем убрали те 3 проверки и с самом конце, перед return true, воткнули MessageBox, то вообще странно, что у вас может этот метод не сработать.

Comment: @Sanvirtus Посмотрите с помощью точек останова что передается между функциями, может проблема станет понятной